# Image Processing in Python to Determine Structure Area

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm working on a Python project where I need to determine the area of a structure from given images.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Read the image.
2. Convert the image to grayscale.
3. Binarize the grayscale image using Otsu's method.
4. Draw contours around the structure.
5. Fill the enclosed area with green to represent the determined area.

However, I've noticed that not the entire structure is captured; often, the marked area is less than what it should be.

I'm wondering if anyone has encountered a similar challenge and can offer guidance. Perhaps there's an alternative method or a tweak to my current approach that could yield better results? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Input Image:

[image: Input Image]

Output Image:

[image: Output Image]

Comment: How do you know what is the full region?  Is that just by your judgement?  Please show a full region and explain why that is correct? Otsu thresholding works when you have a nice two peaked histogram. Your image likely has only one peak or a weak second peak. So it may not be a good representation of a binarized image.

Comment: Hello fmw42, thanks a lot for commenting! Just by my visual judgement. For example on the output image, there are dark grey areas which didn't get detected. But if I try pictures with a clear distinction for example map of countries, it works quite fine. So the problem are my taken images I think. How can I manipulate my images, that my tool works? I tried different approaches with erosion and dilation, but results got worse.

Comment: I do not know if this will help, but you could try increasing the contrast using skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity()

Comment: Just pick a higher threshold. If you need an automated threshold selection, look at the histogram, and what results you get by thresholding at given values, then come up with a method to find that value. For example, the background peak method could work well here. You fit a Gaussian to the background peak (the brighter one here), then pick a threshold at, say, 2 sigma below the mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Image path
path= "/Users/gauravsingh/Downloads/gxETv.png"

# read the image
image = cv.imread(path, cv.IMREAD_COLOR)

# Total Area of the image
_, h, w = image.shape
totalArea= h*w

# Convert the image to grayscale.
imageGray = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# improve contrast of the image using histogram equalisation.
imageEqu= cv.equalizeHist(imageGray)

# Threshold the image to separate background and foreground
_, imageThresh= cv.threshold(imageEqu, 130, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Remove small white pixels outside the structure
imageErode = cv.erode(imageThresh, (3, 3), iterations= 2)

# Count NonZero pixels in the image
NonZeroPixels = cv.countNonZero(imageErode)

# area of structure
structureArea = (NonZeroPixels/ totalArea)
print(f"Area of the Structure is: {structureArea}%")

# Display the image
plt.imshow(imageErode, cmap= 'gray')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Answers are more useful if you explain what the code does.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).